# Routing with id and handle in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to set up rails to use both the ID and the Handle (which is just an URL safe version of the title) of a blog post in the route.

```
match '/articles/:id/:handle', :to => 'articles#show'
resources :articles
```

This works, of course -- but I can't seem to set up the `to_param` method in the model os the longer URL -- with the handle attached, is the default.

This doesn't work (not that I really expected it to):

```
  def to_param
    "#{id}/#{handle}" 
  end
```

I get a `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"articles",` error. I also tried just using the handle, but then Rails generates links to the resource just using the handle and not the ID. I know I can do it with a - in stead of a /, but I prefer the /. Any way to make this work? If I have to add some extra paremeters to my link_to helpers, that's okay.

Comment: I might be off the mark here. How are you generating your link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to pass a `Hash` to `link_to`?

```
link_to "Link", {:id => @article.id, :handle => @article.handle}
```

**Update**

You have to modify your routes:

```
match '/articles/:id/:handle', :to => 'articles#show', :as => :article_with_handle
```

and use the following helper to generate the link:

```
link_to "Link", article_with_handle_path(:id => @article.id, :handle => @article.handle)
```

You can override the helper to simplify things:

```
def article_with_handle_path(article)
  super(:id => article.id, :handle => article.handle)
end
```

and use it like this:

```
link_to "Link", article_with_handle_path(@article)
```

Comment: Yeah, it just creates the URL with query strings.

Comment: Which leads me to repeat my question: how are you generating your link?

Comment: Which leads me to say, exactly like you showed above. You asked if I tried that. I said, yeah -- and it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and sorry if I seemed cranky. I updated my answer, this should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Okay ... I was writing as you were and we were doing the same thing. All looks good!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's what I did to remove the query string problem from the answer above:

Changed the route to this:

```
  match '/articles/:id/:handle' => 'articles#show', :as => :handle
```

Removed the `to_param` method from the model and then generated the link like this:

```
link_to 'Show', handle_path(:handle => article.handle, :id => article.id) %>
```

That works, but could be condensed, obviously, with the helper above. Just change the one line to: `args[1] = handle_path(:id => args[1].id, :handle => args[1].handle)`